# building renderscript for pre honeycomb

Tags: android, adt, renderscript

I have a project which targetVersion is 16 and I'm using SherlockActionBar and support-library for supporting down to API-level 8. I am trying to integrate [CarouselView](http://code.google.com/p/android-ui-utils/downloads/detail?name=CarouselExample.zip) to my project. I am planning to use CarouselView for supported versions and pageViewer for other version. I am using Jetbrains IDEA for development. Normally I can build and deploy my application without any problem using IDEA. However I can't build the application using android-tools. Resulting error is at the bottom.

While investigating the error I realized that renderscript triest compile with api-level 8. I looked at the %sdk.dir%\tools\ant\build.xml and see that renderscript target uses project.minSdkVersion for targetApi. Is this a bug or what?

```
<renderscript executable="${renderscript}"
            includePathRefId="android.renderscript.include.path"
            genFolder="${gen.absolute.dir}"
            resFolder="${out.res.absolute.dir}/raw"
            targetApi="${project.minSdkVersion}"
            optLevel="${renderscript.opt.level}"
            buildType="${build.is.packaging.debug}"
            previousBuildType="${build.last.is.packaging.debug}">
        <source path="${source.absolute.dir}"/
</renderscript>
```

> -code-gen:
>
> [mergemanifest] Found Deleted Target File [mergemanifest] Merging
>   AndroidManifest files into one. [mergemanifest] Manifest merger
>   disabled. Using project manifest only.
>        [echo] Handling aidl files...
>        [aidl] No AIDL files to compile.
>        [echo] ----------
>        [echo] Handling RenderScript files... [renderscript] Found 1 RenderScript files.
>   **[renderscript] Compiling 1 RenderScript files with -target-api 8** [renderscript] Optimization Level: 0 [llvm-rs-cc.exe]
>   D:\Projects\TEB\teb\src\com\pozitron\teb\customwidgets\carousel\carousel.rs:236:14:
>   error: structs containing vectors of dimension 3 cannot be exported at
>   this API level: 'carouselPlane' [llvm-rs-cc.exe]
>   D:\Projects\TEB\teb\src\com\pozitron\teb\customwidgets\carousel\carousel.rs:242:17:
>   error: structs containing vectors of dimension 3 cannot be exported at
>   this API level: 'carouselCylinder' [llvm-rs-cc.exe]
>   D:\Projects\TEB\teb\src\com\pozitron\teb\customwidgets\carousel\carousel.rs:254:21:
>   error: structs containing vectors of dimension 3 cannot be exported at
>   this API level: 'cardVertices' [llvm-rs-cc.exe]
>   D:\Projects\TEB\teb\src\com\pozitron\teb\customwidgets\carousel\carousel.rs:262:26:
>   error: structs containing vectors of dimension 3 cannot be exported at
>   this API level: 'camera' [llvm-rs-cc.exe]
>   D:\Projects\TEB\teb\src\com\pozitron\teb\customwidgets\carousel\carousel.rs:1503:20:
>   error: structs containing vectors of dimension 3  cannot be exported
>   at this API level: 'p' [llvm-rs-cc.exe]
>   D:\Projects\TEB\teb\src\com\pozitron\teb\customwidgets\carousel\carousel.rs:1045:9:
>   error: structs containing vectors of dimension 3 cannot be exported at
>   this API level: 'ray' [llvm-rs-cc.exe]
>   D:\Projects\TEB\teb\src\com\pozitron\teb\customwidgets\carousel\carousel.rs:1092:9:
>   error: structs containing vectors of dimension 3 cannot be exported at
>   this API level: 'ray' [llvm-rs-cc.exe] D:\Proj [llvm-rs-cc.exe]
>   ects\TEB\teb\src\com\pozitron\teb\customwidgets\carousel\carousel.rs:1503:20:
>   error: structs containing vectors of dimension 3 c [llvm-rs-cc.exe]
>   annot be exported at this API level: 'p' [llvm-rs-cc.exe]
>   D:\Projects\TEB\teb\src\com\pozitron\teb\customwidgets\carousel\carousel.rs:1781:17:
>   error: structs containing vectors of dimension 3  cannot be exported
>   at this API level: 'ray'
>
> BUILD FAILED D:\Android\android-sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:645: The
>   following error occurred while executing this line:
>   D:\Android\android-sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:665: null returned: 1

edit: As Selvin suggested I copied renderscript folder and llvm-rs-cc.exe from older version. Now I got the following error:

```
[mergemanifest] Found Deleted Target File
[mergemanifest] Merging AndroidManifest files into one.
[mergemanifest] Manifest merger disabled. Using project manifest only.
     [echo] Handling aidl files...
     [aidl] No AIDL files to compile.
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling RenderScript files...
[renderscript] Found 1 RenderScript files.
[renderscript] Compiling 1 RenderScript files with -target-api 8
[renderscript] Optimization Level: 0
[llvm-rs-cc.exe] Generating ScriptC_carousel.java ...
[llvm-rs-cc.exe] Generating ScriptField_ProgramStore_s.java ...
[llvm-rs-cc.exe] Generating ScriptField_Card.java ...
[llvm-rs-cc.exe] Generating ScriptField_FragmentShaderConstants_s.java ...
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling Resources...
     [aapt] Found Deleted Target File
     [aapt] Generating resource IDs...

BUILD FAILED
D:\Android\android-sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:645: The following error occurred while executing this line:
D:\Android\android-sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:683: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access class com.google.common.base.Platform from class com.google.common.base.CharMatcher
        at com.google.common.base.CharMatcher.precomputed(CharMatcher.java:684)
        at com.google.common.base.CharMatcher.<clinit>(CharMatcher.java:63)
        at com.google.common.base.Splitter.on(Splitter.java:129)
        at com.android.sdklib.internal.build.SymbolWriter.write(SymbolWriter.java:51)
        at com.android.ant.AaptExecTask.execute(AaptExecTask.java:711)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:68)
        at com.android.ant.IfElseTask.execute(IfElseTask.java:120)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:68)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.MacroInstance.execute(MacroInstance.java:398)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:390)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:411)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1368)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:809)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:217)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)
```

Comment: did you replaced whole platform_tools folder? or just (as i wrote) only llvm-rs-cc.exe file and renderscript folder ...anyway try to change targetApi="${project.minSdkVersion}" to targetApi="${project.targetSdkVersion}"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i've got the same problem...

i assuming that you're using newest SDK (21) with platform tool 16...

from this version render script doesn't like structures like

```
typedef struct Ray_s {
    float3 position;
    float3 direction;
} Ray;
```

with float3...
so download older platform tools from:

http://dl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_r15_rc9-linux.zip

http://dl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_r15_rc9-windows.zip

http://dl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_r15_rc9-macosx.zip

make copy of your

C:\adsdk\platform-tools\llvm-rs-cc.exe <= this file

and

C:\adsdk\platform-tools\renderscript <= whole folder

and replace them with the ones from zip

OR

replace float3 with float4 in render script and do other code change(i'm pretty sure that changing only float3 to float4 will not work)

Comment: Hi Selvin, thank you for response. I updated my question please check the edit. Copying from older tools didn't solve my problem. And regarding the replacing float3 with float4 compiling didn't complain about them. However errors occur on defining structs with 3 dimension vectors.                                                          static Plane carouselPlane = {
       { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f }, // point
       { 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f }, // normal
       0.0f // plane constant (= -dot(P, N))
};

Comment: starnge ... it works for me ... did you replaced "C:\adsdk\" with your path to android SDK .... `{ 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f }` should change to `{ 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f , 1.0f}`(add 1.0f at the and) ... but  don't think if it will work either coz calulation with vec4 instead vec3 using one more dimension ...

Comment: `did you replaced "C:\adsdk\" with your path to android SDK` and did you download platform_tools for your OS ...

Comment: apparently there were another problem related to my local settings. I tried on another computer and everything works fine.

Comment: you know that renderscript graphics api is deprecated? and maybe some day it will stop workin on new API lvl...

Comment: Isn't renderscript just introduced in honeycomb? What should I use instead of renderscript. I am specifically interested in carouselView. I am using CarouselView Example introduced in Google I/O 2011 see: http://code.google.com/p/android-ui-utils/downloads/detail?name=CarouselExample.zip&can=2&q=

Comment: yes, but then it was deprecated in API 16 :) https://groups.google.com/d/msg/android-developers/m194NFf_ZqA/WXYHmtUovaMJ just use it ... but test your app on every new API emulator/device:)

Comment: thanks for clarification. maybe I should look for another solution.

Answer (score 3):

Your SDK bug about target API vs. minimum API level is actually a bug in how the Android SDK is compiling your code. As far as using an older SDK/compiler to ignore the float3 issue, please don't do this. This was actually a bug for older compilers and devices, as float3 alignment/packing was not handled properly. The correct solution for older devices is to use float4 (which works fine on all devices). If you use the older compilers from r15, you will end up with code that only works for some subset of older devices.

Comment: problem is when all your shaders where using vec3 not vec4 ... still rsgraphics will stop working someday since it's deprecated :/